# Handling Jackson Parent-Child Serialization

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

I'm using Spring MVC (am new to this), Hibernate and Jackson for my project and am using JSON for data exchange between the server and client.

I have a couple of classes "Employee" and "Address" with a ManyToOne / OneToMany relationship.

I faced the cyclic reference error, however, I was able to resolve that using @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference.

But the problem is, during serialization (I'm querying the DB to get all the employees), Jackson is completely ignoring the Address property and serializing just 3 fields (other fields have been ignored specifically which you can see in the code).

Here's the JSON returned

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "xxx",
        "age": 100
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "yyy",
        "age": 100
    }
]
```

The Employee Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "e_employee", catalog = "emploman")
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private int age;

    private Address address;

    private String modifiedBy;

    private Date modifiedTime;

    private transient int addressId;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(int id, String name, int age, Address address, String modifiedBy, Date modifiedTime) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
        this.modifiedTime = modifiedTime;
    }

    public Employee(String name, int age, Address address, String modifiedBy, Date modifiedTime) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
        this.modifiedTime = modifiedTime;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "age", nullable = false)
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference("employee-address")
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Column(name = "modified_by", nullable = false, length = 50)
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setModifiedBy(String modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "modified_time", nullable = false, length = 19)
    @JsonIgnore
    public Date getModifiedTime() {
        return modifiedTime;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setModifiedTime(Date modifiedTime) {
        this.modifiedTime = modifiedTime;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Transient
    public int getAddressId() {
        return addressId;
    }

    @JsonIgnore    
    public void setAddressId(int addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }

}
```

The Address Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "e_address", catalog = "emploman")
public class Address implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;

    private String country;

    private String state;

    private String city;

    private String streetAddress;

    private String pinCode;

    private String modifiedBy;

    private Date modifiedTime;

    private Set<Employee> employees;

    public Address() {
    }

    public Address(int id, String country, String state, String city, String streetAddress, String pinCode, String modifiedBy, Date modifiedTime, Set<Employee> employees) {
        this.id = id;
        this.country = country;
        this.state = state;
        this.city = city;
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
        this.pinCode = pinCode;
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
        this.modifiedTime = modifiedTime;
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    public Address(String country, String state, String city, String streetAddress, String pinCode, String modifiedBy, Date modifiedTime, Set<Employee> employees) {
        this.country = country;
        this.state = state;
        this.city = city;
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
        this.pinCode = pinCode;
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
        this.modifiedTime = modifiedTime;
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "country", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Column(name = "state", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Column(name = "city", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Column(name = "street_address", nullable = false, length = 500)
    public String getStreetAddress() {
        return streetAddress;
    }

    public void setStreetAddress(String streetAddress) {
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    }

    @Column(name = "pincode", nullable = false, length = 15)
    public String getPinCode() {
        return pinCode;
    }

    public void setPinCode(String pinCode) {
        this.pinCode = pinCode;
    }

    @Column(name = "modified_by", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    public void setModifiedBy(String modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "modified_time", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getModifiedTime() {
        return modifiedTime;
    }

    public void setModifiedTime(Date modifiedTime) {
        this.modifiedTime = modifiedTime;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "employee-address")
    public Set<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(Set<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

}
```

So, basically, the json response I'm expecting is something like below:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "xxx",
        "age": 100,
        "address": {
            "country": "xxx",
            "city": "abc"
        }
    }
]
```

Could anyone please help?

***Update 1***

I've tried getting Addresses from the DB, and employees related to that address is successfully being fetched

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "country": "xxx",
        "state": "yyy",
        "city": "zzz",
        "streetAddress": "abc",
        "pinCode": "12345",
        "modifiedBy": "xxx",
        "modifiedTime": 1400930509000,
        "employees": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "xxx",
                "age": 190
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "xxx",
                "age": 200
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks people.

I was able to resolve this issue by using JsonIdentityInfo on my classes (both parent and child) along with a plugin called jackson-datatype-hibernate through which I enabled a feature called FORCE_LAZY_LOADING

If it helps anyone, below is the code for both the above configurations:

Create a class as below to enable jackson-datatype-hibernate

```
public class HibernateAwareObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public HibernateAwareObjectMapper() {
        Hibernate4Module hbm = new Hibernate4Module();
        hbm.enable(Hibernate4Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING);
        registerModule(hbm);
    }
}
```

Tell Spring to use the above ObjectMapper than the default provided by Jackson:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <!-- Use the HibernateAware mapper instead of the default -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="com.adwitiya.o2plus.utilities.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

As for the JsonIdentityInfo, below is the code. Notice the use of JsonIgnoreProperties (I've used this mainly for all the sets as it creates a recursive big tree and I wanted to avoid that)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "o2_branch", catalog = "o2plus"
)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "id")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"active", "modifiedBy", "modifiedTimestamp", "members", "staff"})
public class Branch implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private Address address;
    private String name;
    private String contactNumber;
    private Integer capacity;
    private String manager;
    private boolean active;
    private String modifiedBy;
    private Date modifiedTimestamp;
    private Set<Member> members = new HashSet<Member>(0);
    private Set<Staff> staff = new HashSet<Staff>(0);
```

Hope it helps more people.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem that can cause this behavior is that this is a lazy-fetched field. And transaction may be finished before serializing to json (depends on your code). Entity may be detached by the time Jackson gets it and getter will return null (or empty list, not sure). You can check this by making field eager-fetched or calling getter before entity will be detached (while transaction is still active).

In our case it was an container-managed EJB transaction and mapper was invoked from Jersey servlet.

Comment: In that case, atleast the field "address" should be available in the JSON with a null value which I don't see in the case I've posted.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the problem I'm facing...and as far as lazy fetching goes, I'm using OpenSessionInViewFilter, so I don't think the session would be closed before the request is completed...this has something to do with Jackson, not Hibernate or Spring, I might be missing some simple annotation or might have added an extra one or something!!